# How to encrypt disk on Manjaro after installation

Tags: manjaro, disk-encryption

I have installed Manjaro Cinamon. How can I enable now full disk encryption?
Does Manjaro provide some GUI for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware of I would say NO. But if you wanted a full disk encryption then you should have tried LUKS while installing the system. That provides a key encrypted disk or drive which can only be accessed using the Key.

In case you forget the key then the only way out of it would be reinstalling everything.

You can most probably reinstall the system (but do make a proper backup of all  the files) or you can follow the following tutorial

https://linuxconfig.org/basic-guide-to-encrypting-linux-partitions-with-luks

I'm providing you the links from where you can understand about LUKS a bit more

1. https://guardianproject.info/code/luks/
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup

And do tell me if you find a way to encrypt the system using GUI interface.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's possible with `cryptsetup-reencrypt`:

> Do you need to change encryption parameters of LUKS device (like volume key, cipher or IV)? Or even switch not encrypted device into encrypted one with minimal effort?
>
> That's where new `cryptsetup-reencrypt` tool from cryptsetup 1.5 can help.

https://asalor.blogspot.com/2012/08/re-encryption-of-luks-device-cryptsetup.html